# Bad characters from CSV into database

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, character

I am trying to figure out why I keep getting bad characters when I import information into my database from a CSV file.

**Setup:**

Database is UTF-8 encoding
HTML Page = UTF-8 Encoding (Meta Tag)

What I'm receiving when the file is imported is. 
[image]

But in the CSV file everything looks clean, and the actual number is +1 (250) 862-8350

So I don't know what the issue is, my hunch is something to do with a form of trimming but I haven't been able to figure out what it is... any light would be appreciated!

Comment: How are you viewing the data in DB?

Comment: What has the HTML encoding to do with this? Are you uploading by a HTML input field and parsing the upload in the server side? If so, the problem is in the way how you parsed the uploaded file. You've got to give more detail about this.

Comment: Which operating sytems are you using? What kind of database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I found out my answer, and it's somewhat embarasing. when my phone number gets put into the database I run it through my cleaner, and then encode the data... But I didn't notice that my database column was set to a small character count... and my encoding was longer that what would be inserted into the database... So in short, I made a my column 64 vs 32 and it solved the problem.

Thank you for your time in trying to help me though!